# Oxymoron Examples

Tags: word-usage

I am trying to write some new oxymoron examples.  If a grammar school stops teaching grammar (drops grammar from the curriculum), would this be called *oxymoronic?*

Comment: That's more *ironic* than oxymoronic.  An oxymoron is really the juxtaposition of two seemingly contradictory words:  The poster child of these is: *Jumbo shrimp*

Comment: @Jim I'll have to keep thinking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coming up with new oxymorons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that may just be a misnomer as grammar and school don't inherently contradict each other. The actions of the school causes it to be falsely identified  rather than the literal meaning of the two words combined.

Comment: Well then, could I call the school *"ungrammatical"?*